# KML Markers with "Details from Google Maps"

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml

When Editing a map in Google My Maps, when I click a pin it show the title (what I set it to) and "Details from Google Maps" which includes address, website, phone, and rating".

When I use this KML on my website (network link) it displays mostly correct (trying to get custom markers to work), however when I click on an marker, it only displays the title (what I set it to).

Do I have to manually add the "Details from Google Maps" in the description section for this to display?

KML

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<kml xmlns='http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2'>
    <Document>
        <name>Spots</name>
        <description><![CDATA[A map that contains all the places.]]></description>
        <NetworkLink>
            <name>Spots</name>
            <Link>
                <href>http://www.google.com/maps/...</href>
            </Link>
        </NetworkLink>
    </Document>
</kml>
```

Comment: Is that data in the KML you export?

Comment: The KML just has the Network Link. Supposedly it is suppose to grab all the data from the link. I updated the post with the KML.

Comment: What does the KML served by the network link look like? Does it have that data in it?

Comment: Has the map and pins (without custom marker image) and the title of the pins.

Comment: By default only the `name` and `description` would show up on the info window. [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer) says 'Clicking on individual features, by default, brings up an InfoWindow containing KML <title> and <description> information on the given feature.'

Comment: Not the question I am asking.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you question.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that the link/file that you used is hosted publicly on the internet. From this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/kml/#your_kml_file), it is a requirement for all applications loading KML into a KMLLayer. Google's servers need to be able to find and retrieve the content in order to display it on the map - this also means that the file can't be on a password-protected page.

This [link](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut#network-links) may help you on how to integrate the `<NetworkLink>` in your KML file.

Comment: It is hosted publicly since the map shows up on my website. Going to Google my maps and create a map will help you understand what I am asking.